# MSBuild, how can I get the second parent

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task

MSBuild (targets file), how can I get the second parent of an address like this?

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LibFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</LibFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This is for one level parent, how can I get the 2nd level? (Parent of the parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the function again, on the previous result:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LibFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</LibFolder>
    <LibFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(LibFolder)))</LibFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Oh didn't try it this way, seems like a nice trick. +1 and marked it as the answer.